# Show the following inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, fractions, substitution, tangent-line-method

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^+$ and $$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} =1$$

Show that $$(a^2 -3a +3)(b^2-3b+3)(c^2-3c+3) \ge 27$$

I tried using using the AM-GM inequality and some algebraic manipulation to who each of the quadratic terms cannot be smaller than $0.75$ and other little results but I am struggling to be able to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are the $a,b,c$ positive real numbers?

Comment: It's wrong! Try $a=1$, $b=1$ and $c=-1$. For positive variables see my solution.

Comment: Yes sorry they are positive, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive variables let $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{x}{3},$ $\frac{1}{b}=\frac{y}{3}$ and $\frac{1} {c}=\frac{z}{3}.$

Thus, $x+y+z=3$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln\left(\frac{9}{x^2}-\frac{9}{x}+3\right)-\ln3\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln(x^2-3x+3)-2\ln{x}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln(x^2-3x+3)-2\ln{x}+3(x-1)\right)\geq0.$$
Let $f(x)=\ln(x^2-3x+3)-2\ln{x}+3(x-1).$

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{2x-3}{x^2-3x+3}-\frac{2}{x}+3=\frac{3(x-1)(x^2-2x+2)}{x(x^2-3x+3)},$$
which gives $x_{min}=1$ and we are done!

Comment: Not the proof that I expected. Was this your first try?

Comment: I tried Jensen before, but it does not work. At least I don't see how it helps.

Comment: This was amazing thank you very much :)